# error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class QString & __thiscall QString::operator=(class QString &&)"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qstring, lnk2001

I'm desperate about finding any information about the mentioned error.

I'm working on visual studio 2010. When I compile my project (in 32 bits), in debug or release, I get the following message :

> 1>heterogeneous.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class QString & _*thiscall QString::operator=(class QString &&)" (*_imp_??4QString@@QAEAAV0@$$QAV0@@Z)
>
> 1>debug\nori.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

I linked QtCore4.lib in Linker->Input, I added Qt\4.8.2\lib to the library directories in Linker->General, and I included Qt\4.8.2\include and Qt\4.8.2\include\QtCore in C/C++->General. It seems to me that they are supposed to define QString. I don't know what else I could do.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Was the Qt that you are using compiled for Visual Studio 2010 x86?

Comment: Also you should link against QtCore4d.lib in debug builds.

Comment: Yes I linked against QTCore4.lib in Release mod and QtCored4.lib in Debug mod. I didn't install the Qt plugin for VS2010 and I installed the qt libraries for win x64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had same issue, but I was using the Qt Libraries for VS2008.

I installed [Qt Libraries for VS2010](http://qt-project.org/downloads#qt-lib) to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Find out where the Qt DLLs are.  You may have to add that directory to Debugging->Environment.

Comment: That will be needed to actually run the application but will not solve the linker errors since you link against import libraries.

Answer (score 0):

After some time, I decided to delete and re-install the Qt libraries, and it works. However, I have no idea why.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

When using Qt4, higher version compilers may report an "unresolved external symbol (operator overload containing a bunch of rvalue references)" error.
This is because Qt4 imposes restrictions on the support of rvalue references by different compilers, and you need to comment out the Q_COMPILER_RVALUE_REFS macro, which is in the header file qglobal.h.

Comment: Compilers don't report "unresolved external symbol" - linkers do.